# A single word for "someone who readily takes responsibility/new tasks"

Tags: single-word-requests

Want to describe a characteristic of a person, in single word, "someone who readily takes responsibility/new tasks"

Comment: *readily takes* **on** responsibility/new tasks*

Comment: How about "intern".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could say that they are **proactive**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactivity):

> Proactive behavior involves acting in advance of a future situation, rather than just reacting. It means taking control and making things happen rather than just adjusting to a situation or waiting for something to happen. Proactive employees generally do not need to be asked to act, nor do they require detailed instructions.

It may not fit exactly, depending on the specific nuance you're looking for, but I'd say there's definitely an overlap in terms of attitude.

Answer (score 5):

Self-starter comes to mind, though that is a compound word, not a single one.

If you could be more clear with how/where you are intending to use this description, it might help.

Comment: Ok, person describes himself as, whenever a new task/responsibility were given, He took it positively/readily not as a burned...hope you get from this.

Comment: I would still use "self-starter" to describe myself or someone else with those attributes.  It is not at all negative.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the hyphenated compound **Johnny-on-the-spot**:

> person who is on hand and ready to perform a service or respond to an emergency (Merriam-Webster)
>
> Being ready to perform a task or duty right away, being there for something;reliable (Urban Dictionary)
>
> A person who is available when needed, as in He always is there at the right time, a real Johnny-on-the-spot. (Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 4):

A particularly **enterprising** person is sometimes called a **go-getter**.

> an aggressively enterprising person (Mirriam-Webster)
>
> a person disposed to initiate action, rather than take
>        instructions; an enterprising person; a person with a strong
>        drive to accomplish useful goals; especially, one whose
>        career progresses rapidly. (Collaborative International Dictionary of English)

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't sure if you wanted a noun or an adjective.

Ready and willing

Willing and able

Go-to person

Person with a can-do attitude

Ever-ready

Reliable

Never say never

Gets things done

Team player

Mr. Initiative

Conscientious

Flexible

A roll-up-his-sleeves person

dedicated

Comment: Was looking for Adjective... I liked Ready and Willing but then needed a single word :)

Answer (score 3):

*[Initiator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/initiator)*:

> noun
>
> 1 A person or thing that initiates someone or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can say he **has the initiative** or he is **an enterpriser**.

> - enterprise (noun)  the ability or desire to do dangerous or difficult things or to solve problems in new ways [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enterprise)
> - an enterpriser (noun) a person who undertakes or engages in some enterprise; entrepreneur. [D.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enterpriser)
> - initiative (noun) "The power or ability to begin or to follow through energetically with a plan or task" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initiative) "the energy and desire that is needed to do something" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initiative)

- He looks like the right guy for that position.  He has the initiative.
- Why don't you take the initiative and introduce yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The term "eager beaver" means a person who is enthusiastic about performing work and frequently volunteers for tasks. It sounds a bit quaint, but does have the desired meaning.

Comment: or just simply eager.

Comment: Yeah, but I was assuming a noun was desired.

Answer (score 0):

Volunteer - A person who offers to do something out of their own will.

Comment: No, actually I'm searching for a word, when one is given a responsibility and they take it up, and give there best.

Comment: 'Committed' then.

Comment: *Go-getter*...?

Comment: @WS2 Sort of informal for my liking...

Answer (score 0):

You could say that a/that person *takes [ownership](http://gog.is/define+ownership) of the problem*.

This doesn't fit your "single word" criterion, however, and simply calling him the problem's owner doesn't express it either, as it almost suggests the problem was his fault!

Answer (score 0):

A person who steps into another's role could be seen as their *successor*, as *stepping up*, or as *taking up* the previous person's mission.